# Dynamic Casting With Generics

Tags: java, generics, types, casting, compiler-construction

The following code, compiles and executes without error:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box <Integer, String> box = new Box<>(30, "Hallo");
        System.out.println(box);
        box.swapItems(box);
        System.out.println(box);
    }
}

public class Box <F, S> {    
    F first;
    S second;

    public Box(F first, S second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    void swapItems(Box <F,S> box){
        F temp = box.first;
        box.first = (F) box.second;
        box.second = (S) temp;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return "Box{first=" + first +", second=" + second +'}';
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
>>> Box {first = 30, second = Hallo}
>>> Box {first = Hallo, second = 30}
```

While on a first look this is alright, it is very much not (to me). In fact, multiple things happens which are very weird.

1. `F temp = box.first;` this lines sets `temp` to be an Integer. So far so good
2. `box.first = (F) box.second;` this line, however, **should NOT be allowed to execute**, except it does. Quite literally, we are casting the respective of: `int a = (int) "Hello";` and this is evidently not ok. So my question is why is it working here? Why do we get the type of `box.first` to dynamically change at runtime, whereas this is forbidden in other situations?
3. `box.second = (S) temp;` even worse, this line is doing the respective of `string s = (String) 30`, and while this is syntactically wrong, it makes at least intuitive sense as 30 could become "30"... however, what happens is that the type of `box.second` becomes Integer and 30 is assigned to it. This makes no sense to me, an integer is being cast to string and as a result the type of the receive variable is dynamically changed to Integer?

Moreover, after this code is run one can continue using box as if nothing happened, only when you try to perform operations assuiming the type of its variable one incours in classcast exceptions (as expected).

I know that the solution to avoid this is to make `swapItems` static and use another generic type variable to force the relationship of types of the box passed as parameters (e.g. `T void swapItems(Box <T,T> box){..}` but the question here is: why are lines 2 and 3 (with notation used above) working? What is happening beneath that makes the compiler/JVM think this was an acceptable execution of lines? Am I missing something ?

**EDIT:**

From duplicated answers linked above, one can summarize the answer to my questions as:
*Java generics are simply syntactic sugar on casting Objects.*

Comment: "The following code, compiles and executes without error" It does produce warnings though, doesn't it? Anyway, besides the cast being unchecked, it seems okay to me that `(F) valueOfTypeS` should compile. After all, unlike `(int)"30"`, there are actually cases where that cast could succeed - namely when given a box where the second type is a subtype of (or the same as) the first type.

Comment: Unfortunately no warning on IntelliJ (default settings). Yes, is it ok for it to compile, but it is not okay for it to (a) not actually perfom the cast and (b) have the final result to be of `typeS` since this - when is not the situation you described - needs to be a class cast exception

Comment: I don't know why the warning wouldn't show up in IntelliJ - it does for me if I copy your code into IntelliJ. Either way you should still be getting unchecked cast warnings from the compiler.